# C# - How do I print a string in another listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, client-server

A part of this code will print the 'New Ip client found', I added a code(*the commented part*) where it will get the hostname. I want that hostname to be printed in a separate listbox. How should I do it? I tried to append it but it wont show in the listbox I provided in the [Design].

```
public void performConnect()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (myList.Pending())
        {
            thrd = thrd + 1;
            tcpClient = myList.AcceptTcpClient();

            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
            string clientIP = ipEndPoint.Address.ToString();
            nStream[thrd] = tcpClient.GetStream();

            // IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.Resolve(clientIP);
            // string sClientHost = ipEntry.HostName;

            currentMsg = "\n New IP client found :" + clientIP;
            recieve[thrd].Start();

            //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                        
            // sb.Append(listBox1.Text);                        
            // sb.Append(sClientHost + " is online.");                       
            //listBox1.Text = sb.ToString();

            this.Invoke(new rcvData(addNotification));
            try
            {
                addToIPList(clientIP);

            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException exp)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the framework you are using?  Is this WinForms, WPF, etc?

Comment: windows form application and .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are referencing main thread from another thread, you can't just do it directly. Cross thread operation is not allowed to prevent deadlocks. Do as following to access your list which in the main thread from another thread.

```
lstYourListBox.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => lstYourListView.items.Add(clientIP));
```

Comment: what is 'lstYourListBox' and 'lstYourListView' shall i put this in the current function or in the listbox1 function?

Comment: lstYourListBox is the id of your list box.Oops typo detected, it should have been lstYourListBox not lstYourListView. Effect of working in ASP.NET haha. Put this code inside your addToIPList(clientIP) method where you must have added items to your listbox.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Windows Forms in a long time so take this for what it's worth.  Try doing the following after you add the text to the listbox:

```
listBox1.Invalidate();
listBox1.Update();
```

Comment: so there is no problem in the append part?

Comment: @user3406220 No, I don't think so.  That looks OK to me.

Comment: @user3406220 BTW, using StringBuilder here is not doing much for you since you just have one string to add to listBox1.Text.  You could probably just do this:

Comment: @user3406220 Oops, hit return.  Try this instead:

listBox1.Text += sClientHost;

Comment: sb.Append(listBox1.Text);  returns an error of 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need to add to the listbox, just replace the listbox1 with the name \ id of your listbox

```
Action action = new Action(() => { 
                listBox1.Items.Add(sClientHost); 
            });
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

Comment: it won't recognize the clientIp (does not exist in current context) if i put it in the listbox1 ..and i need to get the hostname not the Ip

Comment: yes, if i make it currentMsg = "\nHostname found :" + sClientHost;

Comment: so you can get the hostname, and you want to put this into the listbox? am i understanding that correctly?

Comment: If i have understood you correctly i have amended my answer to reflect your need with hostname

Comment: yes i need that hostname to be place in another place which is supposed to be the listbox1.

Comment: ok, try the updated code, but to add to the listbox the code you need is `listBox1.Items.Add( then your variable in here)`

Comment: i still get an error, the variable i am trying to put inside the parenthesis does not exist

Comment: not every ip has a hostname, what happens if you ping the ip address that its coming from `ping -a xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: then itll just get whatever default hostname it has. the code works, my only problem is putting the hostname in another place.

Comment: mine, except the append part because thats where it should print to the listbox which is not working.

Comment: change the append for my code then and that should solve your issue

Comment: it gives this error 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

Comment: ok, give me a few minutes, i have some code somewhere that will allow you to pass this back to the ui